# Start key's token sorts after end token

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to run some processes in Cassandra, using Cassandra 1.2.6 and ColumnFamilyInputFormat. I am getting the stack trace bellow.
    I tryed switching to both `RandomPartitioner` and `MurmurPartitioner` (I re created the keyspaces from beggining in both cases), but the problem persists.
    How to figure why is this happening?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: InvalidRequestException(why:Start key's token sorts after end token)
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$WideRowIterator.maybeInit(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:453)
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$WideRowIterator.computeNext(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:459)
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$WideRowIterator.computeNext(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:406)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader.getProgress(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:103)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.getProgress(MapTask.java:514)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:539)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Start key's token sorts after end token)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_paged_slice_result.read(Cassandra.java:14168)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_get_paged_slice(Cassandra.java:769)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.get_paged_slice(Cassandra.java:753)
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$WideRowIterator.maybeInit(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:438)
... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying call you are using is get_range_slices, which returns a range of rows.  You can either input a start and end token, or a start and end key.  It looks like you are using a start and end key.

The problem with this is that, with the RandomPartitioner (MurmurPartitioner), keys are stored in token order.  The token is obtained by MD5 hashing (Murmur hashing) the key, so token order is in general different to key ordering.  You can therefore only make a get_range_slices request where the end token is greater than the start token.  If you specify a key range, your request will fail if hash(start) > hash(end), which can happen even if start < end.

I don't know what you're trying to do, but you probably want to use the token range.  Or if you are paging through results then set the end key to blank and use the last key given as the next start key.